# Catch segfault from inside arm-none-eabi-gdb target sim?

Tags: gcc, arm, gdb

I wish to execute automated unit tests of my embedded libraries using arm-none-eabi-gdb simulator. I have a problem, that invalid memory access causes nothing in the simulator, while it causes segmentation faults or hard fault exceptions in real-world.

I have a following small program saved as `ub.c`:

```
int main() { *(volatile int*)(void*)0 = 42; }
```

I compile using:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -specs=nosys.specs ub.c -o ub.elf
```

And then execute

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb ub.elf
```

Inside gdb I execute commands:

```
target sim
load
break exit
run
```

The store to NULL seems to completely ignored. You can even set a `break main` and with `si` step to execute the instruction `str   r2, [r3]` with `r3=0` and `r2=42`. Nothing happens. I wish on gdb simulator there would be some anything like "exception/seg fault/branch to hard fault vector or anywhere" that I can inspect/handle in gdb to automate unit testing.

Is there a way to enable the "hard fault exception" in gdb target simulator?
Is there any way I can "trap" invalid memory access, unaligned memory access, similar in arm-none-eabi-gdb with simulator target?

Btw, I use Arch Linux 4.20.6 with arm-none-eabi-gcc 8.2.1.